# Multisite - SMTP not working on other network sites

Tags: multisite, email, subdomains, wp-mail, phpmailer

I have WP Mail SMTP plugin setup on multisite, the email is sent from the parent site successfully, however, when trying the same or another email from the child site gives me following error:

```
ErrorInfo: The following From address failed: info@example.com : MAIL FROM command failed,RNPI Access denied by login ip protect
,550,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: RNPI Access denied by login ip protect
SMTP code: 550SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: RNPI Access denied by login ip protect
SMTP code: 550
```

Can someone suggest me how to fix that?

Comment: 'Access denied by login ip protect' - host issue, you are being restricted it seems that your server IP sending the mail to the SMTP server is not authorized you have to have the IP white listed to send mail.

Comment: If you are talking about the plugin by WPForms, I just want to mention that there is a way to set it up for multisite, to read about it open the file wp_mail_smtp.php and somewhere around the top in the comments read where it says: Specifically aimed at WPMU users...

Comment: @Nikolay yes, that is the issue, previously, the email used to work on parent site as well but now it doesn't work on either. Also, added an mx record in Route 53 AWS, thought it may help, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty obvious from the log entries you posted that this isn't a WordPress issue. I'd suggest working with your hosting provider to resolve the issue.